# How to share architecture-independent latex files across multiple setups

Tags: apt, latex

I have 3 ubuntu computers, 2 of them running 32-bit and one 64-bit. I want to install latex and texmaker on all of them. However, the downloads are pretty large and i don't want to unnecessarily download the same files over again, so is there anyway i can download the common files once and share them among the three computers. Any help will be highly appreciated and thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily share a complete installation of TeXlive (which would have to include all needed architectures) via e.g. NFS; the clients only have to point their `$PATH` to the binary path (e.g. `.../tex/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux/`) relevant for them.